# Facing issue while clicking dropdown button using selenium webdriver code

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

The application I am using is having several dropdown buttons having same xml code. Below is the code which is similar for all dropdown buttons.

```html
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="invContactList" title="" data-original-title="Nothing selected">
```

I have use below code to click the button

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']")).click();
```

using this code application run successfully only once but there after it gives error as: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command. I have removed browser cookies but it wont help.

Can someone please help me with the root cause and solution ?

Comment: Please post the HTML for a few of the buttons. Have you tried a CSS selector like "button[data-id='invContactList']"? Are you sure that you are finding the element you intended? It's possible your locator is finding more than one and the first one available is hidden.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes its working.. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to wait for that element :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']"))).click();
```

> OR

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-id='invContactList']"))).click();
```

> OR

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']"))).click();
```

> OR

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@data-id='invContactList']"))).click();
```

Try it at your end.